# Wicket PageExpiredException when re-login

Tags: exception, jakarta-ee, authentication, wicket, wicket-6

I'm coding a web app use wicket 6.15.
I have a problem:
- login to web and login with user A (tab 1)
- open more tab (tab 2)
- make it experid session like change server time
- in tab 1, when do some thing, `pageexpiredexception` throw will make me go to login again, I login with user A (like before)

> org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.PageExpiredException: Page with id '10' has expired.

-in tab 2, when do some thing `pageexpiredexception` throw make me go to login.

> org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.PageExpiredException: Page with id '11' has expired.

How do I solve this? I want in tab 2 to continue without exception because it uses the same user account.

Answer (score 2):

After creating the second session there is no page with id '11' in it, so PageExpiredException is thrown.
By default Wicket will try to detect the page class from the url and create a new instance of it. If it cannot detect it, e.g. the url is like "/wicket/page?11" then `ApplicationSettings#getPageExpiredExceptipPage()` will be used.

If the login page is being shown in your app then most probably you have custom IRequestCycleListener that catches PEE in its `#onException()` method and redirects to your login page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in  wicket 7 to redirect to login page in `WebApplication class`

```
getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(LoginPage.class);
```

once the login expired it will redirect to your login page.